# Have you got any working DirectCanvas examples from AppMobi.com?

Tags: html, appmobi

Where I can find some working code or any instruction to DirectCanvas from AppMobi.com?
There is some sample code on Git [a link](https://github.com/appMobi/ios) but I can't understand how can I Run it?

Answer (score 1):

Everything right now is targeted towards ImpactJS.  There are sample apps when you purchase the GameProXDK and documentation is found at http://www.appmobi.com/documentation/gamingAPI.html

We are currently working on samples for NON- ImpactJS code.  The main thing is that you have two Webviews, one the canvas calls are executed in, the other is your app.  The documentation talks about that and details how to make calls between the two.

http://forums.appmobi.com has a thread about getting it running standalone with a sample bundle to use.

Comment: As I can see for load AppCanvas (transporter?) I should call AppMobi.canvas.load("index.js") and in "index.js" I can write something like that: var ctx = AppMobi.canvas.getContext("2d");
Is it context of Direct Canvas or not?

Answer (score 1):

Has anbody actually tried using directCanvas seriously? I cannot find a single blog post about somebody actually using it. The whole experience is really bad with this crazy java XDK tool/thingamagica. Took me 20mins to get CocoonJS running.